# Array of doubles sent via intent is full of nulls in the receiving activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

My MainActivity is a quiz where each question includes a *betSize* value and a *potSize* value. After the quiz ends I am sending 2 Double Arrays, *betSizeArray* and *potSizeArray*, from MainActivity to ResultsActivity to display in a ListView. I initialize and populate the arrays in the first activity and use putExtra() to put them in an intent. In ResultsActivity I am using intent.extras?.getDoubleArray(key) to retrieve each array; however the retrieved arrays are full of nulls.

In ResultsActivity.OnCreate() I first tried

**val betSizeArray = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("BET_SIZES")**.

This causes a NullPointerException whenever I tried to access a value from betSizeArray.

Next I tried

**val betSizeArray = extras?.getDoubleArray("BET_SIZES")**.

Having to use safe call  "**?.**"  to get the arrays and to access the array's values (such as **betSizeArray?.get(i)**)  doesn't throw a NullPointerException; however all values accessed from the array are NULL.

Have tried initializing the array in MainActivity inside onCreate() instead, however that just caused NullPointerExceptions whenever using these arrays in MainActivity.

In the function in MainActivity where I create the intent and call startActivity(intent), I tried initializing and populating a testArrayList to make sure the array I was passing into the intent is populated and not full of nulls. However the array retrieved in ResultActivity is still full of nulls. I did not include this test in the following code.

```
var betSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
var potSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
var count = 0

var betSize = 1.0
var potSize = 1.0


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//here an OnKeyListener that eventually calls setNextQuestion() is created
....
}
```

setNextQuestion(), where the arrays get populated:

```
private fun setNextQuestion() {

        //check if 20 questions have been completed

        if (count < 19){

            //values are added to each array

            betSizeArray[count] = betSize
            potSizeArray[count] = potSize
            count++

            ...
            /*new values are created for betSize and potSize for next time
            this function is called*/
       }

       else endQuiz()
    }
```

endQuiz() where the intent is created and startActivity() is called.

```
private fun endQuiz() {

        val resultsIntent = Intent(applicationContext, ResultsActivity::class.java)

        resultsIntent.putExtra("BET_SIZES", betSizeArray)
        resultsIntent.putExtra("POT_SIZES", potSizeArray)

        startActivity(resultsIntent)

    }
```

ResultsActivity:

```
class ResultsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results)


        val extras = intent.extras
        val betSizeArray = extras?.getDoubleArray("BET_SIZES")
        val potSizeArray = extras?.getDoubleArray("POT_SIZES")


        var listData = ArrayList<String>()
        var textData = ""

        //this loop is where the arrays are accessed.
        for( i in 0 .. 19){
            textData = "$" + betSizeArray?.get(i).toString() + 
            " into $" + potSizeArray?.get(i).toString()

            listData.add(textData)
        }

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listData
            )
        resultsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

        assessTextView.setText(assessment)
    }
}
```

The code successfully populates the ListView. However all values accessed from the arrays come back as "$null". Each line in this ListView reads as:

$null into $null

$null into $null

...

Output I would expect if everything went correctly would look something like:

$50 into $85

$15 into $40

...

where the values are random numbers generated in MainActivity and passed to ResultActivity via the arrays and the intent.

I still suspect that I need to initialize the arrays in onCreate() of MainActivity. But that just threw errors whenever adding values to the arrays in MainActivity.

Thanks for any help!

edit: @Azhar92 so I just tried in MainActivity where the intent is created:

```
        val bundle = Bundle()

        bundle.putSerializable("BET_SIZES", betSizeArray)
        bundle.putSerializable("POT_SIZES", potSizeArray)
```

and in ResultActivity:

```
        val bundle = intent.extras

        val betSizeArray = bundle?.getSerializable("BET_SIZES") as ArrayList<Double>
        val potSizeArray = bundle?.getSerializable("POT_SIZES") as ArrayList<Double>
```

and I'm getting a TypeCastException:

```
     Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.ArrayList<kotlin.Double> /* = java.util.ArrayList<kotlin.Double> */
        at com.example.questgen.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.kt:39)
```

line 39 being the first getSerializable(). So it still seems the array that's getting passed through the intent is null for some reason.

```
        val betSizeArray = bundle?.getSerializable("BET_SIZES") as Array<Double?>?
```

casting to Array? instead doesn't throw an error, but the array is still filled with NULL.

final edit:  It's working! I moved all variables to under the class header. Changed array initialization from arrayOfNulls to DoubleArray(20). Took out a lot of private method parameters since I now have class variables that make sense and are accessible. Switched from bundle.putSerializable() to intent.putExtra(). In ResultsActivity I switched from bundle.getSerializable() to intent.getDoubleArrayExtra(). I assume there was some way to make Serializable and bundles work but this is what got me results for the first time. I think you're right about me re-declaring variables somewhere before. Thank you gmetal!

Comment: Try to use getSerializableExtra in your resultActivity instead of getDoubleArray

Comment: Thanks @Azhar92. Added what happens when using getSerializableExtra to the original post at the bottom. Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getDoubleArrayExtra` will return a Java `double[]` which may not include null values. Since you are initialise them with the `arrayOfNulls` method, an `Array<Double?>` will be returned. And when you retrieve it from the extras of an intent, you will need an `Array<Double?>?`, because a null value may be returned.

So you should read them back as `Serializable` values (all Java object representation of primitive types are `Serializable`) and cast them to `Array<Double?>?`:

```
    val extras = intent.extras
    val betSizeArray = extras?.getSerializable("BET_SIZES") as Array<Double?>?
    val potSizeArray = extras?.getSerializable("POT_SIZES") as Array<Double?>?
```

Also note that the type of the betSizeArray on the ResultsActivity will be: Serializable?, because it may be null (e.g. not contained in the bundle), and must be cast to the desired Array? value.

If this doesn't work, this means that you are not doing something correct in your MainActivity. I would first move these variable declarations:

```
var betSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
var potSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
var count = 0

var betSize = 1.0
var potSize = 1.0
```

inside the MainActivity like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var betSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
    var potSizeArray = arrayOfNulls<Double>(20)
    var count = 0

    var betSize = 1.0
    var potSize = 1.0
```

Comment: Tried this where I cast the serializable to "ArrayList<Double>?". Array is still filled with NULL

Comment: It's not an `ArrayList<Double>?`, but an `Array<Double?>?`.

Comment: Tried casting to "Array<Double?>?" but same results

Comment: I edited my answer with some additional information. Check it out, and do follow my suggestion of moving the variables inside the MainActivity. I also believe that you are re-declaring the variables somewhere. Avoid using global variables (e.g. outside of class declaration).

Comment: It's working! I moved all global variables underneath the class header. Changed array initialization from arrayOfNulls to DoubleArray(20). Took out a lot of private method parameters since I now have class variables that make sense and are accessible. Switched from bundle.putSerializable() to intent.putExtra(). In ResultsActivity I switched from bundle.getSerializable() to intent.getDoubleArrayExtra(). I assume there was some way to make Serializable work but this is what got me results for the first time. I think you're right about me re-declaring variables somewhere before. Thank you gmetal!

Comment: Glad it's working. The DoubleArray is a non nullable type (mapped to double[]), which is why you can now use the getDoubleArrayExtra.